# Finding the Length of the Longest Sequence of Swaps to Increase Array Ordering Value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm working on a problem where I need to calculate the length of the longest possible sequence of swaps that increases the ordering value of an array. The ordering value of an array is defined as the number of indices i (1 ≤ i ≤ n) such that a[i] = b[i], where b is the array sorted in non-decreasing order.

I understand that I need to swap elements in a way that each swap increases the ordering value, but I'm struggling to come up with an efficient algorithm that can handle large inputs within the given constraints (time limit per test: 2 seconds, memory limit per test: 256 megabytes, array size up to 3 * 10^5).

So far, I've tried a brute force approach where I perform all possible swaps and check the ordering value, but as expected, it doesn't scale well with larger arrays.

Could someone suggest a more efficient approach or point me in the right direction? Pseudocode or a high-level algorithm would be really helpful.

Comment: Unless you have a situation where you are forced to do a swap that raises the ordering value by 2, computing the length of this sequence is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

In an array, an inversion is a pair of elements in the wrong order. E.g., in [1,2,3] there are no inversion, in 2,1,3 there is one, and in 3,2,1 there are 3.

The number of swaps will be equal to the number of inversions, with each swap undoing one inversion (putting one inverted pair in sorted order).

You can modify merge sort to count inversions in O(n log n), as explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inversion-count-in-array-using-merge-sort/).